# Build script - how to tell if the apache tomcat was deploying my webapp properly?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, build, gradle

We are using gradle for our build process.
We would like that our script will determine if the tomcat deployed our web app properly, if now we would have to recover from that using another script.

1) How can one determine if the tomcat deployed the war properly? is there any more appropriate way to do so other than checking the log file? (feels wrong)

2) How can one determine if the webapp started properly? (with no errors, such as spring autowiring failure) is there any more appropriate way to do so other than checking the log file? (again, feels wrong)

thanks!

Comment: I guess it feels wrong but it's way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I normally create an status page for this task. This status page may contain a DAO to verify the connection to the data base, or any other info such us number of active threads, free memory, error traces in the log files etc. 
Then you can use a cron job to that loads the status page from time to time.if you don't get a 200 OK or if you don't get the information expected on this page you could send an alert mail, etc.

I hope this helps.